# Any eclipse plugin for creating deployment diagram

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml, deployment-diagram

What is the best free plugin for eclipse to draw deployment diagram.

I have `http://www.objectaid.com/`, but we can draw only class and sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the UMLet plugin for Eclipse looks best for you. http://www.umlet.com/

Here is a sample [tutorial](http://www.newthinktank.com/2012/11/uml-2-0-deployment-diagrams/). Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

You are unlikely to find a Eclipse Plugin to do deployment diagrams since that activity is really beyond the scope of an IDE.  However you could use [ArgoUml](http://argouml.tigris.org/) to draw deployment diagrams.  It's free and open source.